# Async in Razor Page @functions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, razor-pages

I'm getting the following error in my Razor Page.

[image]

So I changed it.

[image]

Now the code will run but I get warnings.

> 1>obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Areas.cshtml.g.cs(256,200,256,202): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
>   1>obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Areas.cshtml.g.cs(282,200,282,202): warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.

Can anyone tell me exactly what Razor Pages needs here?

**UPDATE:**

Here is my complete `@functions` section.

```
@functions
{
    async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RenderArea(Area area)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="@area.CssClass">
                <p class="compact">
                    <a href="/Area/@area.Id" class="font-weight-bold">@area.Title</a>
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(area.Description))
                    {
                        <br />@area.Description
                    }
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="@area.CssClass">
                <img src="~/images/Edit.png" class="edit-area button-img" data-id="@area.Id" title="Edit" />
                <img src="~/images/Delete.png" class="delete-area button-img" data-id="@area.Id" title="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I see the rest of the method?

Comment: @BlueEyedBehemoth: Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is an error, the second is a warning.

[This is the change](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/pull/11514) that implemented the first error message. So that's certainly intentional.

I suspect the warning is a result of not seeing the word `await` anywhere inside the method and not understanding that `~/` causes an implicit `await`. So I think that might be a bug and [should be reported to Microsoft](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues).

But at the moment, I don't think you have an option other than ignoring the warning.

Comment: After the change, I get the two warnings and no errors. Reporting to Microsoft.

Comment: Link to issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20055